# How to firmly place CMOS battery on Asus X200MA Laptop motherboard?

Tags: laptop, battery, cmos

I have this old Asus X200MA laptop motherboard and while changing the CR2032 CMOS battery I found out that the old battery popped out fine, but the new battery does not fit in tightly in the same spot. I have also tried inserting the old battery as well just to rule out size mismatch.

See how it floats from a side. When I turn the board upside down which is its default placement, the battery just falls.

It seems there might have been something in there tightly holding it in place. But I did not see anything broken anywhere while popping out the old one.
See all the snaps and guide me please. Using an insulating tape is my last option to hold it in place.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Press it down until it clicks.

Comment: It does not click in place. I can press it down but it automatically slightly pops up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using answer space only for illustration…

I don't know that particular clip, so this is a pure guess, but it perhaps looks like the tabs designed to hold the edge of the battery in may have disintegrated & broken away.

[image]

Comment: I think most likely you are right. Laptop CMOS battery holder seems to have a different design that that of desktop motherboards. There must have been those two tabs which being so thin  now have disappeared. I did lightly press the battery slightly inside and it poped out and it must have disintegrated those two tabs. I will accept this as an answer. Now Insulating tape or super glue seems to be my next option. That leaves me to a new question about need of CMOS battery in laptop, I will ask it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Press hard, its a tight fit, but that is what keeps it from failing out. When inserted it will be flush with the plastic holder all the way around the circumference.

Comment: I have done it numerous times on desktop motherboard. However laptop motherboard is for the first time and even if I press it hard, it still slightly pops out. I think this being a very old laptop, the structural strength of the plastic holder seems to have been lost. The bottom connector pushes it up I guess.

Comment: Then you need to improvise, use a sharp toothpick and wedge it between the battery and housing as you press the battery into the housing.